# Extract data from a list and get it into a tidy tibble, R

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list (list in code example) I wish to loop throu and extract data from and get into a tidy dataset (target tibble in code example). The list consists of 5 elements, each is suppose to represents a page in an application form. Each element is one string.

1. From the first element I wish to extract the information relating to the words number and organization.
2. Between the words Start(element 3) and stop(element 5) I aim to extract the information relating to name and info. It's the information between the colon(:) after name and info and the linebreak I wish to extract. Perhaps a regex solution is possible? In the code example there is 3 names and 3 infos. I strive to build a generic function that can handle any number of names and infos within the defined boundaries (start, stop).

How could I approch this problem in R? Grateful for any help. I have made some attempts using str_extract_all() but they have all failed.

```
library(tidyverse)

target <- tibble(number = c("10", "10", "10"),
          organization = c("TEST", "TEST", "TEST"),
       name = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
       info = c(12, 1, 43))

string1 <- "Application \r\n Date: 2020-09-23\r\n number: 10\r\n organization: TEST \r\nMail: x@x.com\r\n
             Page 1(5)\r\n"
string2 <- "Application \r\n Date: 2020-09-23\r\n ZZZZZZZZ\r\n
             Page 2(5)\r\n"
string3 <- "Application \r\n Date: 2020-09-23\r\n Start\r\n name: X\r\ninfo: 12\r\nmiss: NO\r\nname: Y\r\ninfo: 1\r\nname: Z\r\
             Page 3(5)\r\n"
string4 <- "Application \r\n Date: 2020-09-23\r\n info: 43\r\n miss: YES\r\nPage 4(5)\r\n"
string5 <- "stop\r\nname: ZY\r\ninfo:45\r\nMISS:-\r\nPage 5(5)"

list <- as.list(c(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5))
```

Comment: Are you sure your "target" matches input data, there should be 5 rows?

Comment: Yes. I aim to have one row for each name (X, Y, Z).  And I only want to extract data from the names whitin the start stop boundaries. This is an attempt to reproduce the conditions for my real case, which is to extract data from large application forms (pdf).

Comment: I see, did you try using [tabulizer](https://docs.ropensci.org/tabulizer/), used for extracting tables from PDFs.

Comment: No. I use pdf_text() from pdftools. The function returns one long string with linebreaks for every page in the pdf. Perhaps tabulizer is better? It requires Java installed, and that is a problem for me when I use my work computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want to achieve:

```r
str <- paste0(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5)
str_extract_all(str, regex("(?<=start).+?(?=stop)", dotall = TRUE,ignore_case = TRUE))[[1]] -> strs

str_match_all(strs, regex("name: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?info: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n", dotall=T))[[1]][,-1] -> mat

tibble(name=mat[,1], info=mat[,2], number=as.numeric(str_extract(str, "(?<=number: )\\d+")),organization=str_extract(str, "(?<=organization: ).+(?= +\\r)") )
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  name  info  number organization
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>       
1 X     12        10 TEST        
2 Y     1         10 TEST        
3 Z     43        10 TEST
```

#### Explanations:

I'm using lookaheads `(?=pat)` (resp. lookbehinds `(?<=pat`)) to check if the following (resp. preceding) characters match  pat.

- `str_extract_all(..., "(?<=start).+?(?=stop)")` get the text that's between start and stop.
- `name: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?info: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n` :

  1. `name: *` match `name:`  followed by any number of spaces.
  2. `([^\\r\\n]+?)` capture one or more characters that are different from a carriage return `\r` and a newline `\r`, the `?` quantifier is to match the minimal number of characters possible i.e in regex terms make the `+` quantifier  non greedy.
  3. `\\r\\n.*?` match a literal `\r\n` and `.*?` any number of characters as less as possible.
  4. `([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n` capture .... then match a literal `\r\n`.

Comment: I'm truly grateful. I don't grasp all the regex.  i will of course look into it more deeply, but if it's not too much trouble for you, would you guide me throu what's happening? Why did you make it as a string and not a list? Has a string some advantages in this case?

Comment: @Henrik I added explanations and simplified the code. I made it a string so that I could get the data between the start and stop and because the third name had it's info in another page. It's easier to manipulate the string this way. also If you have multiple starts and stops in a single file I can accomodate for that.

Comment: I think I follow the regex. Fun! I ran of course into a new problem because I need to get my real data into a single string like the one you used. Pdf_text returns a list with one string per page. One element is the whole page.

Comment: if it returns a list you can turn it into a vector by using `unlist(ur.lst)`

Comment: I've tried. Still a char with 16 dimensions, one for each page, I Think I need to do some more. Found this: https://blog.datazar.com/extracting-pdf-text-with-r-and-creating-tidy-data-f399011549cc

Comment: use `paste0(ur.lst)` just as I did in the answer

Comment: `paste0(ur.lst, collapse="")` to make it one string